# Middleware in .net core not working, letting me step into it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

I was realizing that I need to write some middleware for httpcontext etc.., but thus I tried to take even an example from Microsoft, and the problem is that even with breakpoints on the outside ... `app.Use` and `app.Run`  , with F11 it will not step into the code.

How can I even step into this code to see the values?

startup.cs file

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{

    var request = new Request("api/menu/create", Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("currentApplicationId", 1, ParameterType.QueryString);


    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    // UPDATE :  Code above prevented from being able to step into below?  

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        var cultureQuery = context.Request.Query["culture"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultureQuery))
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureQuery);
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        }

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        return next();
    });

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(
        $"Hello {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName}");
    });

}
```

Comment: Which line of code do you want to step into? Put a breakpoint on it?

Comment: I debugged the code you placed and breakpoints hit on both middlewares, What's wrong?

Comment: I put breakpoint on app.use and app.run and inside both of them and running the application it hits the outside but NEVER goes inside

Comment: put your breakpoint inside app.Use or app.Run not outside

Comment: I have put the breakpoints inside, it never hits them

Comment: @ChadJacobs Only thing I found wrong is that it should be `next()` instead of `return next();` Please give a try with that and let me know.

Comment: Oh, let me edit question,  some of these other lines of code seem to prevented from entering?    hang on while I post and update with code that was above it.

Comment: @ChadJacobs See my previous comment and check.

Comment: Another wrong `app.UseMvc` should be the last middleware in the pipeline. Please also update this and give a try.

Comment: I showed the code the is BEFORE , notice the // comment  Update   -  I moved it back down and sure enough the code will not run .   Lost as to which line is the reason why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188018/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-chad-jacobs).

Comment: Tried the Chat,  its blocked at my job /work

Comment: Ok, so app.UseMVC should be moved to last lines...

Comment: Yes, confirmed that I had to move the `app.UseMvc(..` to be last .   Thanks

Comment: Has it worked for you? and moreover have you replaced `return next()` with `next()`?

Comment: It works with moving app.UseMvc under...   It does not work with `next`  , complains about needing a return on the lambda  `=>`

Comment: Okay! With return has it worked?

Comment: Yes,  thank you very much

Comment: Welcome! I have posted it as answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core request processing pipeline `app.UseMvc()` should be the last `Middleware` as follows, otherwise next middlewares would not call.

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var cultureQuery = context.Request.Query["culture"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultureQuery))
    {
        var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureQuery);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    }

    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
    return next();
});

app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(
    $"Hello {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName}");
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use adding middleware in the mid or beginning

```
//Add our new middleware to the pipeline
app.UseMiddleware();

app.UseSwagger();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Comment: I was creating middleware to authenticate bearer tokens and this comment helped me. I had my middle ware DI at the end and it was never called to authenticate tokens.